# How to get Hash value from url in magento

Tags: url, review, product-urls

my Url is like this

```
http://localhost/b/index.php/review/product/list/id/27/#review-form
```

how can i get value after #

```
$val="review-form";
```

Comment: it is javascript related. just use `window.location.hash`

Comment: where you want to get this # value

Comment: serverside it will not be available in the request_uri. It stays in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript you can get hash value like this

> var hash = window.location.hash;

and in php you can do like this

> $url = parse_url("http://localhost/b/index.php/review/product/list/id/27/#review-form");
>
> $val = $url["fragment"];

$val is your hash value